# Get ID of containing div to pass in jeditable jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, parent, jeditable

I am using jeditable to update multiple items on a page, however there are a number of different records which can be modified on one page, so I need to pass the unique ID of each record along with the updates. Each record is wrapped in its own div with the id of record id.

I have managed to get the Jquery to work, however it gets the ID of the first Div and not the containing div.

Here is the html simplified

```
<div id="outer">
 <div id="left"> 
  <div id="3">
    <p><strong>Web ID: </strong>3</p>
    <p><strong>Record Date type (008): </strong><span class="editable_select" id="0085" style="display: inline">eng</span></p>
    <p><strong>Collection ID (035): </strong>(WlAbNL)1002</p>
    <p><strong>Date Created (260): </strong><span class="click" style="display: inline" id="260">1910 -</span></p>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

And here is the Jquery that works, but selects 'Outer' instead of '3'. I think the problem is in my var rec definition?

```
<script id="source" language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
   var recid = $('.click').closest('div').attr('id');

     $('.click').editable('ajax/save.php', {     
         cancel    : 'Cancel',
         submit    : 'OK',
         indicator : 'Saving...',
         style  : "inherit",
         tooltip   : 'Click to change...',
         submitdata : function() {
              return {rid : recid }; 
            }
     });
     $('.edit_area').editable('ajax/save.php', { 
         submitdata : {record: "<?php echo $rec_id; ?>"},
         type      : 'textarea',
         cancel    : 'Cancel',
         submit    : 'OK',
         indicator : '<img src="img/indicator.gif">',
         tooltip   : 'Click to change...'
     });
     $(".editable_select").editable('ajax_save.php', { 
            submitdata : {record: "<?php echo $rec_id; ?>"},
            indicator : '<img src="img/indicator.gif">',
            data   : "{'Eng':'Eng','Cym':'Cym'}",
            type   : "select",
            submit : "OK",
            style  : "inherit",
    });
 });
```

UPDATE -

The following gets the correct ID now, I had to change VAR to use a function.

I figured it out. Instead of just trying to set recid I needed to focus the function so this works.

```
var recid;
   $('.click').focus(function() {
      recid = $(this).closest('div').attr('id');
   });
```

However as I have three classes that trigger this (click, edit_area, editable_select) is it possible to replace '.click' with something else so it works on any of the editables using it? Or do I need to duplicate the above?

Answer (score 0):

Why not try using `parent()`, instead of `closest()` here:

```
var recid = $('.click').parent('div').attr('id');
```

and see what comes out.

Comment: I did try that, but it comes out with the same 'outer'. I think its the 'click' bit in the Var (JS newbie) which is wrong. I have also tried this and that returns nothing, I need it to know where it is if that makes sense. I will update my question